# On refresh react application I need to get from componentWillReceiveProps values for input text

Tags: forms, reactjs

I have the following problem and I really need help on that.

```
export class DeviceEdit extends React.PureComponent<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let data = this.props.devices.data.find(device => device.id === 
    `${deviceID}`) || {};

  this.setState({ value: data.name })

  }

  componentWillMount() {
     let data = this.props.devices.data.find(device => device.id === 
     `${deviceID}`) || {};

  this.setState({ value: data.name })
  }

 componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  let data = newProps.devices.data.find(device => device.id === 
  `${deviceID}`) || {};

  this.setState({ value: data.name })
 }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

render() {
  const { error } = this.props;

  return (
   <FormLabel>Internal ID</FormLabel>
     <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange= . 
          {this.handleChange} />
     </Form.Label>)
   }
  }
```

So what I want is that when I refresh the page, I want to get the the this.state.value on my input.. which in this case I am not able to do that. So I would like to know what I am doing wrong here. If I set it on value on the input I did get what I want, but then I have an warning like that:

```
A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component
```

What can I do?

Comment: try `onChange= {() => this.handleChange()}` ... also you probably want to define `handleChange` :P

Comment: yes I forgot to add this on my post, so this is not the problem

Comment: check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/949wrjzl0r

Comment: @EgorEgorov we don't need to create several functions and pass `event` directly. In your example you created two functions instead of one. It's redundant.

Comment: Well it seems to fix the "uncontrolled -> controlled" error

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should handle changes there and you can use just `value` on the input field instead of `defaultValue`.

For example:

```
export class AdminDeviceEdit extends React.PureComponent<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '',

      // if it comes from props by default 
      // you can use, if not just leave as it is
      value: props.value
    };
  }

   handleChange = e => {
      this.setState({value: e.target.value});
   }

   render() {
      const { error } = this.props;

      return (
         <form>
           <FormLabel>Internal ID</FormLabel>
           <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
         </form>
      )
   }
}
```

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you want to make controlled input but use `props.value` as a default value. What if you do:

```
export class AdminDeviceEdit extends React.PureComponent<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.value,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if(this.props.value !== newProps.value) {
      this.setState({ value: newProps.value }) // reset input value
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const { error } = this.props;

    return (
     <FormLabel>Internal ID</FormLabel>
       <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
     </Form.Label>)
   }
}
```

Certainly get rid of `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`. You don't need them here.

Comment: I updated my post above. My problem is actually that I need the componentWillReceiveProps function, because my data comes there on refresh page, on componentWillMount and DidMount I lost my data